# How do you add two values from the same table and store in calculated record in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have one tables here:

```
equipment
ID,  Owner, Type,    Count  
 1   Bob    phone      10         
 2   Larry  computer   11
 1   Bob    computer   11
```

What I am trying to do is add the computers that Bob, with id 1, to the computers of Larry's, with id 2. I'm trying to increase the count. The count should be 11+11=22. The new computer count for id 2 should be 22 and should update like this in the database:

```
equipment
ID,  Owner, Type,    Count  
 1   Bob    phone      10         
 2   Larry  computer   22
 1   Bob    computer   11
```

If Bob did not have any computer, meaning there was no record with ID = 2, then the record should be created.

Here is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO EQUIPMENT(`ID`, `OWNER`, `TYPE`, `COUNT`)
SELECT 1 as t.ID, t.OWNER, t.TYPE, t.COUNT 
FROM EQUIPMENT t 
WHERE t.ID = 2
on duplicate key
update 
   COUNT = COUNT + t.COUNT;
```

Comment: I think you should show more data here.  What happens if other computers with different IDs were to appear in the table?

Comment: I added more data. I saw your concern. I'm just trying to indicate that 'Bob' added the same amount of computer's 'Larry' has to his current count. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: a disaster waiting to happen, how are you going to know how much bob really has??

Comment: what do you mean @e4c5

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `insert` to update a row?

```
update equipment e cross join
       (select e1.* from equipment e1 where e1.id = 1) as e1
    select e.count = e.count + e1.count
    where e.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this

```
UPDATE Yourtable a
       JOIN Yourtable b
         ON a.NAME = b.NAME
            AND a.ID = b.ID + 1
SET    a.Count = a.Count + b.Count
```

Comment: @th3r1singking - Fine.. What should happen when there a 3rd row with `ID = 3` for `type = computer`